# What is the purpose of CHAR_LIMIT in strings.xml?

Tags: android, android-xml

Why do some Android projects list a "CHAR_LIMIT" in comments above each string in strings.xml? For example, from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/strings.xml:

```
<!-- [CHAR LIMIT=25] String for confirmation button to enable a feature gated by the battery saver warning-->
<string name="confirm_battery_saver">OK</string>
<!-- [CHAR_LIMIT=NONE] Battery saver: Feature description, with a "learn more" link. -->
<string name="battery_saver_description_with_learn_more">To extend battery life, Battery Saver:\n&#183;Turns on Dark theme\n&#183;Turns off or restricts background activity, some visual effects, and other features like \u201cHey Google\u201d\n\n<annotation id="url">Learn more</annotation></string>
```

Googling turns up a few other examples, but no explanation. I don't believe Android documentation covers this. And unlike tags like `<xliff:g>` it doesn't seem to be an official, functional component of Android. My best guess is that it's a convention some projects use to indicate "when you translate this, make sure the translated version doesn't have more than X characters or else it will break the UI!" Or perhaps, vice versa, "if you're using this String, make sure the UI still looks good with a String X characters long"

My thought is that the UI should always be built to be as flexible as is reasonable, given the possibility for translations of different lengths, and the possibility of different text sizes. Also that translators should strive for the translation to be more or less the same size as the original text, instead of going from, say, 10 characters to 50 characters when translating. So I would think this "CHAR_LIMIT" would be completely unnecessary and could be dropped. (I ask, because I'm touching up an old open source project that uses this.)

Is my understanding of "CHAR_LIMIT" correct, or what is it for, and should it be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when you translate this, make sure the translated version doesn't have more than X characters or else it will break the UI!" Or perhaps, vice versa, "if you're using this String, make sure the UI still looks good with a String X characters long

That's pretty much my understanding of it.

I searched around a bit for where this clue is used, and I found only a single place: [stringslint.py](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/tools/stringslint/stringslint.py;l=157). This is a lint script that seems to be used on `strings.xml` files. Maybe the project you're talking about used this script? The file docs say:

> Enforces common Android string best-practices.  It ignores lint
>   messages from a previous strings file, if provided.
>
> Usage: `stringslint.py strings.xml`
>   Usage: `stringslint.py strings.xml old_strings.xml`
>
> In general:
>
> - Errors signal issues that must be fixed before submitting, and are only   used when there are no false-positives.
> - Warnings signal issues that might need to be fixed, but need manual   inspection due to risk of false-positives.
> - Info signal issues that should be fixed to match best-practices, such   as providing comments to aid translation.

So that goes along what you were saying. It's a clue for translators but can also be used for lint checks, hence the easily parseable syntax.

I also tried to search for pages explaining how one would translate the Android System, hoping `CHAR LIMIT` would be mentioned somewhere. But it doesn't seem like the community can contribute their own translation, so I found no such page.

Note that there's also a [`BACKUP_MESSAGE_ID`](https://cs.android.com/search?q=BACKUP_MESSAGE_ID) that's declared in the same way for some string resources. It seems related to the system Settings app, but I don't know any more that than.

EDIT: I found another script using it: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/tools/grit/grit/tool/android2grd.py, although this time it's `CHAR-LIMIT`.

Comment: Sounds like my guess is correct - that this "CHAR_LIMIT" thing is an uncommon tactic with very marginal value... I'm going to move away from it where I can.